# How to reliably determine last commit date in remote repository?

Tags: git, makefile

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25564443/1714490) answer and it is *almost* exactly what I need.

Difference is that will print date for human eyes, while I need to check it in a Makefile.

In particular I need to rebuild a certain file IFF something changed in repo after its creation.

I might not have a local copy of repo, so I might need a full "git clone" (possibly shallow), but I cannot directly use file dates because git does not preserve them.

I need something like:
   `if myfile is_older $(git log -1 --format=%cd origin/master); then ...` or, in `Makefile`:

```
myfile: $(somefunc $(shell git log -1 --format=%cd origin/master))
        commands to rebuild myfile
```

but I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Slavomir, a key ingredient will be the `--date` option, but not with the `raw` value but rather the **`unix`** value (in order to only get the number of seconds from the epoch **in UTC, without the timezone**).

```
$ git log -1 --format=%cd --date=unix
1582030040
```

(cf. [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---dateltformatgt)).

Then, you'll be able to use the **`date +%s -r myfile`** shell command to get the timestamp of `myfile`.

(cf. [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)).

Finally, you can devise a Makefile function to ease the comparison, which leads to a minimal working example like the following one:

> Makefile

```
# Return 'true' if $(1) does not exist or is older than branch $(2)
check_repo_change = $(shell if [ ! -e $(1) ] || [ $$(date +%s -r $(1)) -lt \
  $$(git log -1 --format=%cd --date=unix $(2)) ]; then echo true; fi)

# Note that you'll probably need to run "git fetch" at some point
BRANCH := origin/master

all: myfile
.PHONY: all

ifeq '$(call check_repo_change,myfile,$(BRANCH))' 'true'
myfile:
    set -x; echo ok >> $@
else
myfile:
    $(info No change detected in branch $(BRANCH))
endif
.PHONY: myfile
```

**Note:** the `.PHONY` option is mandatory so that the `myfile` target will be triggered even if the file already exists and doesn't have (more recent) dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the date format, try to add **--date** option.

For example:

- rfc

  ```
  git log -1 --format=%cd --date=rfc
  Wed, 5 Feb 2020 16:34:38 +0200
  ```
- relative

  ```
  git log -1 --format=%cd --date=relative
  13 days ago
  ```
- iso-strict

  ```
  git log -1 --format=%cd --date=iso-strict
  2020-02-05T16:34:38+02:00
  ```
- short

  ```
  log -1 --format=%cd --date=short
  2020-02-05
  ```
- raw

  ```
  git log -1 --format=%cd --date=raw
  1580913278 +0200
  ```

For more documentation, look into: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Maybe I would use "raw". Is this date formatting convenient for your script?